# Issue with HaProxy - trying to use it for TCP failover?

Tags: linux, networking, nas

I've been struggling for a week with a problem and hoping someone more experienced can give me some insight.

I have 2 QNAP NAS which are being used on Windows machines for mapped drives. I thought it would be cool to have a failover for them. The data across the 2 NAS systems is replicated in real-time over my network and the data is identical.

Example:
QNAP1 - 192.168.50.35
QNAP2 - 192.168.50.36

I have a linux machine (Ubuntu) running in VMware workstation, hosted on Windows 2016 server. Right now, the Ubuntu machine has a a static IP of 192.168.50.200. QNAP uses smb2 on port 445. The windows clients in my environment map network drives as an example to \192.168.50.200\Files, \192.168.50.200\Stuff, etc.

Below is the haproxy configuration

```
log /dev/log local0
log /dev/log local1 notice
chroot /var/lib/haproxy
stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-listeners
stats timeout 30s
user haproxy
group haproxy
daemon



defaults
log global
mode tcp
option httplog
option dontlognull
timeout connect 5000
timeout client 50000
timeout server 50000
errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

listen QNAP
bind 192.168.50.200:445
mode tcp
option tcplog
default_backend QNAP_NAS

backend QNAP_NAS
mode tcp
option tcplog
log global
balance roundrobin
timeout connect 5s
timeout server 10s
server Asgard1 192.168.50.35:445 check inter 5s fall 1 rise 10
server Asgard3 192.168.50.36:445 check backup
```

So the above configuration works...technically. I can map drives on the windows clients like \192.168.50.200\Stuff, etc. However, when I try to test the failover, by restarting the NAS the Windows client is currently connected to, everything is still unavailable and the file shares cannot connect. It seems that when I map the drive on the windows client, it connects to 1 of the NAS, say 192.168.50.35. If I reboot that NAS @ 192.168.50.35, all the network shares disconnect.

I can see in the haproxy logs that it registers the NAS as down, 0 live and 1 backup, etc. but the failover just doesn't work.

It is entirely possible I'm missing a piece, or not understanding something, so I'm hoping someone can help. Remapping the drives doesn't seem to work either. The Windows client seems to want to still go to the NAS that is shutdown. Maybe because there are other drives mapped via the .200 address that are actually pointing to .35 in the load balancer?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Kind of driving me nuts lol

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Samba is running on your NAS? They should have access to DFS Namespaces for shares, which would allow what you're trying without including extra software

Comment: QNAP NAS uses smbv2 but I have no idea how to use DFS with that.  Not much experience with DFS.  I thought that was a Windows server thing?

Comment: Do you have terminal access to your devices? Hopefully with SSH?

Comment: So actually it looks like QNAP does support DFS via folder aggregation "portals" but according to the documentation, if one of the NAS servers fails it all fails, which is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Yes I have ssh access to both NAS devices.  Here is the documentation on the DFS https://wiki.qnap.com/wiki/Dfs

Comment: So then you can setup another machine (i.e. your HAProxy machine) to run Samba, and enable the DFS root there, pointing to the two QNAP devices

Comment: Will that give me failover?  The point is so that if someone is accessing something on either NAS and one of them goes down, I don't want down time...or at least minimal downtime.  if the user needs to click the network share again I'm fine with that, as long as access is maintained

Comment: It will, as long as your proxy machine doesn't go down. Otherwise, you'll need the two QNAP devices, and two Front-End devices. You could do it with just the QNAP, depending on the Samba version (not the smb version), and some extra networking (i.e. giving the NASes second IP addresses that are private to them, then let them fight over one IP address for the clients)

Comment: Interesting.  I was reading about failover and kept seeing things about haproxy and keepalived.  But with keepalived it seems that you need to do the virtual IP on the server itself...in this case the NAS...and I'm not sure it supports package downloads through ssh like that.  It looks like the QNAPs support smbv3...does that change anything or help at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96727/discussion-between-mike-van-dunk-and-canadian-luke).